# how to delete a member of vector which is a member of class

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which is a system of library.
I have made a class of books which has setter and getter for setting and getting each information of a book; such as the name of book and the name of author.
then I made a vector of my class.
for example `vector <books> book(1000)`.
for instance for `book[1] the name is abcd` and `the name of author is efg`
now I need to declare a function which can delete a member of vector , for example delete book[1].
but I dont know how to do it.
I will be appreciate If anyone can help me!

```
class books
{
public:
    books()
    {

    }
    void set_name(string input)
    {
        name = input;
    }
    void set_author_name(string input)
    {
        author_name = input;
    }
    string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    string get_author_name()
    {
        return author_name;
    }

private:
    string name, author_name;

};
vector<books> book(1000);
```

Comment: I'm not so clear about, what you mean with _"member of a vector"_? Do you want to delete a specific **element** of that vector by using it's index? You can do this using the `erase()` function of `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: To begin with, why do you create a vector of `1000` "empty" books? If you know you might add around 1000 books during the life-time of your program, [*reserve*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) it instead.

Comment: As for your problem, [a decent `std::vector` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) could be helpful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean for example for deleting book[1] I should write 'book.erase(1)' ?

Comment: @pantea it sounds like your problem is rather how to find the necessary iterator at that index (check @Dario's answer). You can apply `std::find_if()` to get the one matching your search criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) is here for you!

It accepts an iterator to the element to be deleted, so something like

```
book.erase(book.begin() + idx);
```

would work to delete the element at index `idx` (in `O(N)` time)